# Trimming strings with forward slashes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why do the following queries result in 'q' instead of 'sq'?

```
SELECT TRIM('entities/sq', 'entities/')
SELECT TRIM('entities//sq', 'entities//')
SELECT TRIM($$s/sq$$, 's/s')
SELECT TRIM($$s///sq$$::string, $$s///s$$::string)
```

I'm guessing I need to escape the forward slash, but backslashes are not helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRIM removes the characters (not the string) in the second parameter from the first parameter

I mistakenly though it was trimming the entire string from the front and back.

Instead it is trimming each character from the front and back.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trim

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace) not [TRIM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trim), trim removes all the indivual tokens listed from the start and end of the input string, while match tokens are found.

Aka it is used to trimmed excess white space and the likes.

Replace with the default or explicit empty string is the thing you want.

```
SELECT 
    column1
    ,TRIM(column1, 'entities/') as trimmed
    ,TRIM(column1, 'einst/') as trimmed2
    ,REPLACE(column1, 'entities/', '') as replaced
from values
    ('entities/sq'), 
    ('prefix kept entities/sq'),
    ('no match');
```

Reordering the filter input for the trim shows how they get the same result, and this also shows the replace working.

| COLUMN1 | TRIMMED | TRIMMED2 | REPLACED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| entities/sq | q | q | sq |
| prefix kept entities/sq | prefix kept entities/sq | prefix kept entities/sq | prefix kept sq |
| no match | o match | o match | no match |